# characterize convergent sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, analysis

Suppose that there is a strictly decreasing sequence $\{a_i\}$ such that $\sum_i a_i=1$. Given a rational number $r$ with $0<r<1$, is it possible to characterize for which subsets $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ the sum $\sum_{i\in A} a_i$ will be less than or equal to $r$?

Of course there are some properties, for example that there is a cofinal set such that the sum over that set (and any subset of it) is less than or equal to $r$, but there are still some other subsets over which the sum might be still less than or equal to $r$. I really have no idea how to address this question...

Comment: For a particular example, take $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 1/2^i$. Pick a rational $r$. Now look at it's base expansion in base $2$. This will give you the subsets for which it's equal to $r$.

Answer (score 1):

Your observation that any subset of a cofinal set that adds up to $\leq r$ will also be $\leq r$ is a good one, which gives you the same cardinality of possible subsets (namely, same cardinality as ${\mathbb P}({\mathbb N})$) compared to the maximal possible cardinality of possible subsets. If you want some sort of "exact" characterization for all other sets, it will be hard because for example there may be some finite subsets that add up to exactly $r$. But finding these subsets is an NP-hard problem even for a finite support sequence (i.e. finitely many non-zero values). So you probably can't come up with any "concrete easily computable" descriptions of these finite subsets that add up to $r$, other than the obvious, i.e. simply saying the sum is equal to $r$.